# What happens if there is only one candidate to the Moderator Election?

Tags: discussion, election

As of today, there is only one candidate for the [2014 moderator election](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election). As there are two moderation positions available, what will happen if there is only one candidate?

Comment: There were 2, but now if only one, then only one can be elected.

Comment: There are 6 Moderator candidates for this Election http://gis.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1 only 2 can be elected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that, had the Nomination phase ended with only one nomination (or only two) for the two positions available, then the Election phase would not have been required, and the one nominee (or two nominees) would have been appointed.

This understanding seems to be supported by the result of a [WebApps election in a Meta SE Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78411/moderator-elections) where three nominees for three positions were elected unopposed without an Election phase occurring.

As it turned out there were six nominees, and so the Election phase was required.  However, there were not enough nominees to require a Primary phase between the Nomination and Election phases.